What does the cursed status do in Shogun Showdown?
I just gained the skill Combo Curse in Shogun Showdown, which has the following description:

When you perform a combo kill, a random enemy is cursed.


Clear enough, except it doesn't actually describe what the cursed condition does. I assumed after cursing an enemy  I'd get a description, but even after cursing an enemy and hovering over them in info mode, I didn't get a description of what curse does.

What does the cursed status do in Shogun Showdown?

It curses them. Lol, I had to do it.

I discovered the answer to this question shortly after my run died, due to unlocking a new item which actually described what cursed does:

Cursed targets take double damage on the next hit.



Like the curse ends up making the enemy loose their guard. Like Wanda doing mind tricks on Tony Stark. I'm a super nerd.
